# Node.js Function Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, undefined

I'm writing code that parses HTML fetched from a webpage, and I am having an issue where my function returns `undefined`.

```js
function getVideoUrl(category) {
    PathLoader.load(config.category_url + category['id']).then(function(document) {
        let soup = new JSSoup(document);
        let tag = soup.findAll("li");

        tag.forEach((tag) => {
            if (tag.attrs.class) {
                if (tag.attrs.class.startsWith("pcVideoListItem")) {
                    return config.view_video_url + tag.attrs['_vkey'];
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

let random_category = getRandomCategory();
let video_url = getVideoUrl(random_category);

console.log(video_url);
```

The function `getVideoUrl()` is the one that returns `undefined`, as you may have guessed. I am utterly confused.

Comment: search stackoverflow for how to return value from asynchronous function..

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the `getVideoUrl` method. The `forEach` is looping through the array of elements, but it doesn't return anything above it.

I think what you should use is `find` instead of `forEach`.

Try:

```js
const tags = soup.findAll("li");
const matchedTag = tags.find(tag => tag.attrs.class && tag.attrs.class.startsWith("pcVideoListItem"));
const videoUrl = matchedTag ? `${config.view_video_url}${matchedTag.attrs['_vkey']}` : '';
```

Also, only ever use `let` if you intend the value of the variable to change. Otherwise always use `const`.